# Как проверить имя параметра GET запроса в Sping?

Tags: java, spring, get

Для маппинга GET запроса использую аннотацию `@GetMapping`:

```java
@GetMapping(params = {ParameterName.SORT_BY})
    public List<GiftCertificate> findAllSorted(@RequestParam(value = ParameterName.SORT_BY) Set<ColumnName> columnNames) {

        return service.findAllSorted(columnNames);
    }
```

`ParameterName.SORT_BY` - это обычный enum.

По запросу:

```xml
http://localhost:8080/gift-certificates?sort_by=name
```

я попадаю в данный метод, всё нормально.
Но почему при указании параметра ``, которого не существует в маппинге, по запросу:

```xml
http://localhost:8080/gift-certificates?sort_ABRAKADABRA_by=name
```

Я попадаю в данный метод:

```java
@GetMapping
    public List<GiftCertificate> findAll() {
        return service.findAll();
    }
```

Почему и как сделать проверку параметров GET запроса?

P.S. Вот это уровень, когда минусатор боится объявиться в комментариях и тыкают наугад причину закрытия вопроса, потому что подходящей не существует. Это ж как должно бомбить пуканы :)

Comment: Если убрать атрибут `params` то тоже будет попадать в запрос?

Comment: @RomanC, `22:02:15.946 [RMI TCP Connection(59)-127.0.0.1] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'giftCertificateController' metho`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Если просто проверить параметры**

Первое что пришло мне в голову пришло, это проверять запрос на возможные параметры примерно так:

```
@GetMapping
public List<GiftCertificate> findAll(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (!request.getParameterMap().isEmpty())
        return; // Любое действие, если параметры есть
    return service.findAll();
}
```

**Вариант с опциональными параметрами**

В вашем случае напрашивается другой способ решения - сделать эндпоинт со всеми возможными параметрами и обрабатывать их наличие или отсутствие. Небольшой примерчик:

```
@GetMapping()
public List<GiftCertificate> findAllSorted(
        @RequestParam(value = "foo", required = false) Optional<String> nonRequiredFoo,
        @RequestParam(value = "bar") String requiredBar) {
    if (nonRequiredFoo.isPresent()){
        return service.findAllSorted(columnNames);
    }
    return service.findAll();
    
}
```

Ссылочка на почитать: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param